# Flash Video Player to play MP4 files for Web

Tags: flash, mp4

I am looking for a flash video player that can play MP4 files and can be embedded in the web page. I know that JW Player can do this but its not free for commercial use. I have searched this site, there are examples for flv players but none of mp4 player.

Comment: IIRC, any Flash player is able to play MP4. All Flash video player products use Flash's video rendering engine, they just provide additional functions around it (controls etc.)

Answer (score 3):

[f4player](https://github.com/gokercebeci/f4player) - simple but it works.

Comment: Can you change the link on your post if possible because now, f4Player is on my website under http://gokercebeci.com/dev/f4player

Answer (score 0):

You can use flowplayer, which has a free GPL version.

Answer (score 0):

Even i am looking for various players which are free for Commercial use. I came across couple of them but it was of little use when tried running on different browsers.
Below are few free player as per my knowledge:

1) FLV video Player
http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/flv-mp4-video-player

2) Video-Js
Check for it online. You should get it.

There are many others which are free for non-commercial use. (Bad luck)

If you are looking for fallback then HTML 5 Video tag is available. But if u are looking for a player which will work for mp4 and flv you need to get a player.

For your convinience i have given below the code for fallback. Considering that we have mp4, flv files available for same video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <object data="small.mp4" width="320" height="240">
       <embed src="small.flv" width="320" height="240">
      </object> 
    </video>
```

Make sure that you refine the code before using.